# Downloading youtube video through if and elif statement using youtube_dl

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to download a video with subtitles or without subtitles using the if and elif statement.Currently only my first option is working and when I choose the second option in spite of 2nd option the 1st option is running again.

Currently, my implementation is:

```
import youtube_dl

def switch_demo(x):

    switcher = {

                1: "With Subtitles", 
                2: "Without Subtitles", 
    }


    return switcher.get(x,"Invalid Option")

x = int(input("Select the option\n1.With Subtitles\n2.Without Subtitles\n\n"))

print(switch_demo(x))

link=input('Please enter a url link\n')


if switch_demo(1):

    ydl_opts = {"writesubtitles": True}

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:

        ydl.download([link])

elif switch_demo(2):

    ydl_opt = {}

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opt) as ydl:

        ydl.download([link])
```

I would like to able to download the video with or without the subtitles with both of the two options working.

Comment: What does `if switch_demo(1)` mean, in your opinion?

Comment: You need to pass ```x``` to ```switch_demo```

Answer (score 0):

You wasn't passing `x` to the function so you was always never going to change the outcome, that being said I have re-written your code.

```
import youtube_dl

switcher = {
    1: "With Subtitles",
    2: "Without Subtitles",
    }


def switch_demo(x):
    return switcher.get(x, False)


print("Select an option")
print(*["#{} {}".format(i + 1, switcher[i + 1]) for i in range(max(switcher.keys()))], sep = "\n")
option = int(input("> "))
link = input('Please enter a url link\n')

useSubtitles = switch_demo(x)

ydl_opts = {"writesubtitles": useSubtitles}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the function switch_demo return value as a criteria to drive your if statement. Problem is python considers any non-null value as a true statement so that's why your second choice never get to run